# Figuring out a program communication

Tags: linux, embedded, gnu

I have an embedded gnu/linux on an arm device running a program and I can telnet it. I want to know how the program sends commands to the device so I can make my own program to send those commands but when I want it to. I'm pretty sure it writes to something in `/dev`.
How do I know which file in `/dev` (I know its not really files) a program is writing to and what?
For reference its on armv5tejl chip with 2.6.27.47 kernel. I also have its tool-chain so I can compile programs to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `lsof` (list open files), you can see which files each process has open. You should find the device node your process uses there. Alternatively, you can find out the PID (process ID) of your program using `ps aux`, then look at the open file descriptors of the process at `/proc/$pid/fd`, where $pid is the PID of your program.

To find out what the program is writing, probably the easiest thing is to use strace to trace all system calls the program does. (With strace, you can also find out which file the program opens.) You could also replace the file the program writes to with an empty file, if possible, or, if necessary, with a dummy kernel driver, which records everything it receives.

Comment: I can't modify the kernel, its loaded from some sort of ROM every boot, all I can do is after the system starts

Comment: In /proc/$pid/fd/ all I see is numbers

Comment: Use ls -l /proc/$pid/fd to see the files the symbolic links in the directory point to. If the device node is on a writeable partition, you can try replacing the node with an empty file. If the kernel supports loadable modules, you should be able to load your own driver (but it shouldn't be necessary).